# TCPDF Grey Border / Outline on PNG

Tags: php, png, tcpdf

When adding a base64 PNG image to a PDF using `TCPDF v6.3.2`, there's a grey border on the sides:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$value = explode(',', $value);
$value = $value[1];
$pdf->Image(
    '@' . base64_decode( $value ),
    $this->position('x'),           // X
    $this->position('y'),           // Y
    $this->size('width_mm'),        // Width
    $this->size('height_mm')       // Height

);
```

And here is the image if I just write the decoded base64 to a file (with some sketching over it, you can see there are no grey borders):

[image]

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: What version of TCPDF? Is this behavior limited specifically to base64 PNGs? Does the image have an alpha channel? Can you show us some code that generates this image?

Comment: I need to test this with non-base64 Images, it's a jpg that is being converted to png (jpg -> uploaded to html5 canvas > exported to base64 png) and the channels for the output png are `srgba` - so it seems that there is an alpha channel. i've also updated my question with version and code snippet.

Comment: What do you get if you write out the `base64_decode()` return value to a file?

Comment: @RoAchterberg completely valid PNG output without any grey borders.

Comment: @RoAchterberg I think I solved it, it looks like setting resize=TRUE in the Image() arguments fixes it